# warning LNK4017: DESCRIPTION statement not supported for the target platform; ignored

Tags: c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

When I porting source code from VC++6 to VC++9 on visual studio 2008 I got this warning.

> warning LNK4017: DESCRIPTION statement not supported for the target platform; ignored

I opened the `*.def` file that given me this warning but I still don't know how to fix this warning. This is the content:

```
; sctcomDLL.def : DLL 用のモジュール パラメータ宣言
LIBRARY      "SCTCOMDLL"
DESCRIPTION  'SCTCOMDLL Windows Dynamic Link Library'
EXPORTS
; 明示的なエクスポートはここへ記述できます
```

Comment: It's only a warning - either ignore it or remove the `DESCRIPTION` line. Nothing bad will happen.

Comment: Thank Roger Rowland so much

Comment: @RogerRowland: any insight in what happened to that? MSDN does not tell much about it, except that it's a reserved keyword. AFAIK, it writes that string into the .rdata section of the PE file. Ain't that supposed to be shown in tools like Windows Explorer when you click on "Details" of a DLL or EXE file?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Indeed, according to [this MSDN doc](https://web.archive.org/web/20100628022800/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984816(VS.71).aspx), it "writes a string into an .rdata section".